# Find string in files with patterned exception

Tags: regex, unix, grep, find

I need to find occurrences of strings in a list of files but there's an exception, say the text files have references to the word "world":

> This is the world

And I updated "world" into "new world", so it becomes:

> This is the new world

I need to validate the changes, so I want to search for:

```
world
```

however it will find the "world" in "new world" as well, so there's an exception that the result should be where "world" occurs but not when there's "new " in front of it.

What's the regex for doing this with `grep` or `find`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about negative look behind:

```
(?<!new\s)world
```

Comment: Thanks, let me try!

Answer (score 0):

This should work using egrep

```
egrep "(new\s)?world" file.txt
```